# Window.parent and Window.top returning null

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile-safari

When I call `window.parent` and `window.top` from my iFrame both return null in Chrome and iPad safari, however they both work in Firefox.

A lot of similar posts say the solution is to put the iframe html file on a server, however mine is already on an Apache Tomcat instance and is accessed with `localhost:...`

There is no variable in the JavaScript which overrides the keywords parent or top.

Getting this to work in chrome isn't a big deal, I'm more concerned with iPad safari.

Any possible tips or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: And are the iframe and the parent are on the same domain?

Comment: No they aren't.  The main page and the iframe page are ran on two different Apache Tomcats.

Comment: Run a test when both pages are from same location. If when that works, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: Hmm, the main page I'm using is ran on a liferay server and the iframe is ran on an alfresco server.  I'm not sure if you're familiar with those tools, but it makes putting them on the same server very impractical if not impossible.  If this is the issue, are there any other alternatives to accessing properties of a parent window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, you are in two different domains, and I am betting you have control over them.

You can look into [HTML5 post message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) so you can talk between the domains.

Comment: `window.top` should not return `null` in cross-domain scenarios; instead, you'll get a runtime `DOMException` (with `DOMException.name === 'SecurityError') when you access certain properties of the object returned from `window.top`, such as `window.top.contentWindow.origin`.